How to "CreatePurchaseOrder" via API-Acumatica
I'm trying to create purchase order through a web service endpoint into acumatica web services
my url: https://{baseUrl}/entity/Default3/20.200.001.001/CreatePurchaseOrders/process
here is some details from acumatica screenshots




and this my json example:
{

"entity": {

    

},

"Details":[

    {

    "Location": {"value":"05"},

    "InventoryId": {"value":"1MWDFSSA-M"},

    "OrderQty": {"value": 1.00},

    "UnitCost": {"value": "20" },

    "OrderNbr": {"value": "Code-000395200"},

    "VendorId": {"value": "V10199"},

    "VendorName": {"value": "VendorName"},

    "RequestedOn": {"value": "05/15/2024"},

    "Date": {"value": "05/19/2024"},

    "Selected": {"value": "true"},

    "LineNbr": {"value": "1"},

    "Customer": {"value": "CODE1035800"},

    "CustomerName": {"value": "James Web"}}
    ]
}

it returns 204 messagge without adding any new line to my purchase order screen
Thank you
